# trying to install MERN-Social-Network from git hub node.js version v6.10.0

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm-install

im trying to install MERN-Social-Network 
from git hub [node js code by Faiyaz Shaikh
yTakkar](https://github.com/yTakkar/MERN-Social-Network)

and face this error :

```
www@www-PC MINGW64 /d/Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master
$ npm start

> vue-mini-social-network@1.0.0 start D:\Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
D:\Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master\routes\user-routes.js:25
app.post('/user/signup', async (req, res) => {
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master\app.js:19:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXMRQ.jpg)

Comment: please post your node version. `node -v`

Comment: my version v6.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad you said in the comments your Node.JS version is `v6.10.0` unfortunately this version doesn't support `async/await` functions.

You can check Here: https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

`Async/await` support starts from version `7.0.0` where you need to add the `--harmony` flag to enable ES6/ES7 features. From `7.6.0` it is supported.

So, there are multiple ways you can achieve the same result.

1) Use `Promise` instead of `async/await`
2) Use `babel` to transpile the code into ES5. You can do this by running the code through `babel-load` if you are using webpack(mostly used for frontend products)
3) You can update your node to `>7.6.x`

Note: If you see in the `package.json` of that repository you can see that it is recommended to use node>8 for this project (accorind to the author)

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 8.0.0"
},
```

Comment: I'll try thanx grt effort

Comment: If this solves your problem(after checking) then mark the answer as accepted to help others in same problem.

Comment: www@www-PC MINGW64 /d/Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master
$ npm start

> vue-mini-social-network@1.0.0 start D:\Vue-Mini-Social-Network-master
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
App running..  the code running thanx

Comment: If it is working mark it as accepted. there is a tick mark button right below the question.